# How to free used memory after loading differents page using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to free memory after an Ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418034/how-to-free-memory-after-an-ajax-request)

I want to load different pages using AJAX but that pages have script into it, so when I load a page and show to the client, the script will run and then when I load other page, the script will remain and still active. How can I solve that by removing the script to free memory?

Example:

I have a page with this javascript function:

```
function detailTableInputFocus(id) {
    var DIV = document.getElementById('detail').getElementsByTagName('DIV')[0], input = document.getElementById(id);
    DIV.scrollTop = DIV.scrollHeight;
    input.select();
    input.focus();
};
```

When I load other page, I can call `detailTableInputFocus` with javascript and with Google Chrome I noticed that the used memory are increasing.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Can we have a some more information aobut what kind of pages your loading, what scripts are you running?  how are you noticing the memory using?  can we see the javascript you are using to load the pages?

Comment: @Patricia I'm creating a WebApp for billing in Chile, the app have a header with navigation bar and I'm handling onclick event for every link (<a>), but every page is static page and every page do action with javascript, example see my edit question.